# Wait For a window with some text in title using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

With `TaskList` you can check if a specific window exists or not.

```
tasklist /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq TargetTitle"
```

But it seems it will work only if the exact window title exists. I need to find a window title if it contains some words, for example if there is a window title containing `Target` then `YES` else `NO`.

Is this possible using command prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
tasklist /v /fo:csv /nh | findstr /r /c:",[^,]*Target[^,]*$" > nul 
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo NO
) else (
    echo YES
)
```

Get a verbose (`/v`) task list, in csv format (`/fo:csv`), without headers (`/nh`) and check if the searched text is found (`findstr` with an adecuate regular expression) in the last field (the title)

Answer (score 0):

Use wildcards like **`*`**

`tasklist /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq Target*"`